# i am trying to download excel file when i click on anchor in html "<a>Download</a>"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a  href="/App_Data/Files/Example.xlsx"download>Download</a>
```

I am using this code but this is not helpful

Click to Download Sample EmpMaster File Format

Comment: Will work fine if you have valid path associated in `href` attribute!

Comment: when i download file error is failed or no file

Comment: As mentioned in the earlier comment, You must have valid path...

Comment: yes path is valid but its still not working

Comment: Right click on the `<a>` tag..Right click on the URL..Open in new tab..What does it say ?

Comment: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: I repeat, You must have valid path!

Comment: i checked 100 times even drag the file into html file

Comment: As I do not have access of your file-system, I can not help! ;(

Comment: Maybe with  `<a  href="/App_Data/Files/Example.xlsx">Download</a> ` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking your path it means you are trying to **directly access the file inside App_Data** folder

**App_Data files cannot be accessed directly via URL for security reasons**, you need a server side code to transfer to different folder, or flush it on the response stream

See same solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302253/how-to-view-a-file-after-uploading-it-to-app-data-uploads-in-mvc-3-with-razor)

Comment: i want to download that file not uploading or reading

Comment: yes, you cannot access it directly via URL, for example http://www.myapplication.com/App_Data/Files/Example.xlsx, if you try this on browser, it will show error 404. You need to put it on a different folder like http://www.myapplication.com/Resources/Files/Example.xlsx before you can download/view it

Comment: working fine thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
<a href="App_Data/Files/Example.xlsx" download>Download</a>
```

Format and validation of the path is so important make sure you double check it.

Possible values:

- An absolute URL - points to another web site (like href="http://www.example.com/default.htm")
- A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like href="default.htm")
- Link to an element with a specified id within the page (like href="#top")
- Other protocols (like https://, ftp://, mailto:, file:, etc..)
- A script (like href="javascript:alert('Hello');")

check out links below for more information:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Answer (score -3):

Please use `<a  href="~/App_Data/Files/Example.xlsx">Download</a>` code.

Comment: it is same as i mention above

Comment: I have add "~/" sign Zubair sadiq